# Read encoded files with Python

Tags: python, decode

I have a `filename_00001.pmt.dat` file generated from a MATLAB-based software that I am trying to read with Python (3.9.4 64-bit). According to the software documentation:

> If it is desired to write your own code to load the files (for instance if you need to perform analysis outside of MATLAB) the following provides information about how to read the files.
>
> > (Ex: filename_00001.pmt.dat): This file contains raw binary data of samples written as signed 16-bit integers. The order that samples are written is:
> >
> > > [Channel 1 Sample 1, Channel 2 Sample 1, ..., Channel N Sample 1,
> > > Channel 1 Sample 2, Channel 2 Sample 2, ..., Channel N Sample 2, ...,
> > > Channel 1 Sample M, Channel 2 Sample M, ... Channel N Sample M]

I know I have 1 channel and 12500 samples, so I expect to generate an array of 25000 elements.
I have tried the following in Anaconda3 Spyder 5.1.5 on Windows 10:

```
with open('filename_00001.pmt.dat', 'r', encoding='utf-16-le') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

I obtain a list `lines` with no errors, but it is nowhere close the expected output and I keep getting non-decoded characters.
Is there something I am missing?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You should probably use 'rb' to get the binaey data instead of trying to decode it into unicode

Comment: It's a binary file, you can't decode it like that. Best bet is to find a reader. Did you try this? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's a binary file you should use the mode 'rb' and not 'r' as 'r' is for human readable files like .csv or .txt files.
Then you also probably don't need the encoding parameter